# Flex Spark Datagrid fixed column, horizontal scrolling

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

How can I make my datagrid have its first column fixed and scroll the reset horizontally and vertically?

Comment: The MX DataGrid has a column named lockedColumnCount and lockedRowCount. It doesn't look like those are on the Spark DataGrid.  I don't see an obvious way to do this in Spark; but I'd look for properties like this in a layout class; and if you can't find them then you may have to create your own layout class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spark Datagrid currently does not support locked rows and columns. Your only options if you need locked columns is either the old mx Datagrid or AdvancedDatagrid OR our [Ultimate](http://www.flexicious.com/Home/IndexUltimate) datagrid.