# lockedColumnCount in spark datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I hava an application that is in flex 3 and we are migrating it to Flex 4.5, I have a class which extends the mxDataGrid, and it's using the propery lockedColumnCount which doesn't exist in spark datagrid. Isn't there a property in spark datagrid a property that is equivalent to the property lockedColumnCount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spark data grid does not support locked rows and columns. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650039/flex-spark-datagrid-fixed-column-horizontal-scrolling)